# Change <md-progress-linear> height

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm failing to overwrite the `css` for `<md-progress-linear>`.

They have the following code to set the `height`of the progress bar in their `sass` file:

```
$progress-linear-bar-height: 5px !default;

md-progress-linear {
  height: $progress-linear-bar-height;
}
```

Even when I change `5px`to `1px` it still doesn't change. Leaving out the height, doesn't change anything either.

Even when I put it in my own `sass` file, it doesn't overwrite it:

```
md-progress-linear {
  height: 2px !important;
}
```

Am I overlooking something here?

```
$progress-linear-bar-height: 1px !default;

md-progress-linear {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: $progress-linear-bar-height;

  padding-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

 <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate" ng-if="showLoader"></md-progress-linear>
```

Comment: This is Angular Material? Can I get the full syntax please.

Comment: I did some google search and all the same. Most doable suggestion was to edit the main CSS file of angularmaterial and edit `<md-progress-linear>` this tag's primitive css on basis of what you want at place of making a work around.

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 15. This works for me:

```css
:host ::ng-deep mat-progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
}

:host ::ng-deep mat-progress-bar .mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner {
  border-top-width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You saved my afternoon :)
`mat-progress-bar {
 height: var(--height);
}

mat-progress-bar .mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner {
 border-top-width: var(--height);
}
`

with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` for those who wants to get ride of the deprecated ng-deep

Answer (score 2):

The following should work. First we set the height of the progress-bar container and then the linear bar, both to 20px.
These two elements together help increase the height of linear progress bar.

```
md-progress-linear .md-container {
    height: 20px;
}

md-progress-linear .md-container .md-bar {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation of why it works? It would make for better answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As the height is set on more than one element:

```
md-progress-linear {
  height: $progress-linear-bar-height;

  .md-container {
    height: $progress-linear-bar-height;

    .md-bar {
      height: $progress-linear-bar-height;
    }

    .md-dashed:before {
      height: $progress-linear-bar-height;
    }
}
```

You either overwrite all of these or do it like I did it:

File variables_material.scss:

```
$progress-linear-bar-height: 3px;
```

File main.scss:

```
@import "variables_material";
@import "vendor/angular-material/angular-material.scss"; 

@import …
```

This will configure the height of the progressbar to 3px;

Answer (score 1):

You can use scaleY on md-progress-linear element.

`transform: scaleY(2);
transform-origin: bottom;`

Answer (score 1):

In Angular Material 15 the CSS variable `--mdc-linear-progress-track-height` is referenced internally to set the height of the progress bar. The developers leave it unset and fallback to a value of 4px but you can set it. As a caution, the variable seems undocumented and they may consider it an internal implementation detail. Depend on it at your own risk.

In my situation, a component that includes a progress bar, I set this variable on the host and was able to resize it.

```
:host {
  --mdc-linear-progress-track-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more detail of how to implement?

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-mdc-progress-bar {
    --mdc-linear-progress-track-height: 24px;
    --mdc-linear-progress-active-indicator-height: 24px;
}
```

this is what works for "@angular/material": "16.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 10. This works for me:

```
.mat-progress-bar-element {
  height: 50px !important;
}

.mat-progress-bar {
  height: 50px !important;
}
```